# Describe two different isomorphisms between U(20) and U(16)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

I'm starting abstract algebra, and I'm currently stuck on this problem: **Describe two different isomorphisms between U(20) and U(16).**

Not sure to understand how there can be two different isomorphisms between two groups. I thought that if two groups are isomorphic, it means that there exists a bijection that maps the two groups. But in this case, it means that there exist two bijections between U(20) and U(16)?

Could someone clarify/explain how to approach this problem and tell me if I'm right to think that this means that two bijections exist?

Thank you,

Comment: There are, for instance, two isomorphisms between $\Bbb Z_3$ and $\Bbb Z_3$. One is $x\mapsto x$, the other is $x\mapsto -x$. _Often_, we are only interested in whether isomorphisms exist at all and don't care much about the exact number. But some times we need more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have here several isomorphisms. The first one, arising from CRT, is
$$
U(20)\cong U(4) \times U(5),
$$
because $\gcd(4,5)=1$. Then we have isomorphisms
$$
U(4)\cong C_2,\quad U(5)\cong C_4.
$$
Finally we have an isomorphism
$$
U(16)\cong C_2 \times C_4.
$$
Note that the isomorphisms $U(20)\cong C_2\times C_4$ and
$U(16)\cong C_2\times C_4$ need not coincide.